# What are the multiplication properties of symmetric, anti-symmetric, triangular and diagonal matrices

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

I am study linar algbera and I am looking for all the multiplication properties of symmetric, anti-symmetric, triangular and diagonal matrices

For example:
If $A$ and $B$ are diagonal matrix so $A \times B$ = diagonal matrix as well.

Comment: Product of diagonal matrices is diagonal, of upper triangular matrices is upper triangular, but of symmetric or anti-symmetric ones is not always symmetric or anti-symmetric. See appropriate entries in wikipedia for clarification.

Comment: Product of symmetric matrices is however symmetric if these matrices commute. Appropriately also product of commuting skew-symmetric matrices is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is defined for any two matrices with matching dimensions, i.e. for any $A \in \mathbf{K}^{n_a \times m_a}$ and $B \in \mathbf{K}^{n_b \times m_b}$ for any field $\mathbf{K}$, we have the following rule, iff $m_a = n_b$
$$
(A \cdot B)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{m_a} A_{ik} \cdot B_{kj},
$$
for any $i \in \{1, \dots, n_a\}$ and $j \in \{1, \dots, m_b\}$ and thus the resulting matrix $C := A \cdot B \in \mathbf{K}^{n_a \times m_b}$.

E.g. for diagonal matrices the above rule boils down to the multiplication of corresponding elements of the matrix, given the sizes of matrices are the same.